# Missing artifact in vaadin start project (maven issue)

Tags: eclipse, maven, vaadin

I was just about to get started with the vaadin start project (https://start.vaadin.com/). I downloaded it and imported it into eclipse. However after that I got a Maven import error on line 112+ telling me there is a "Missing artifact org.vaadin.artur:a-vaadin-helper:jar:1.5.0"

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

All other dependencies can be resolved. I do not have a custom settings.xml for maven. Refreshing does not help.

Comment: Supplemental repository needed as described in answer...

Comment: custom repository is already described in the .pom

Answer (score 1):

The artifact is located in the Vaadin Addons repository (for which there is a definition in the `pom.xml`). Perhaps you are using a Maven proxy that does not include this repository?

Comment: I use default maven settings fwik.

Comment: You could try going into your local Maven repository (`.m2\repository\org\vaadin\artur\a-vaadin-helper` from your home folder). If there's an `1.5.0` folder in there, delete it, and try again.

Comment: I do not understand why, but that worked for me :-) Thank you Erik

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, my guess is that a previous attempt to download failed for some reason. Maven doesn't try downloading it again until some time has passed (unless forced), instead it just checks in your local repository that it failed the last time, and informs you that it does not exist, without trying again.

Comment: In my case, the problem was because of maven proxy.